# ¿Cómo embeber una página de JavaScript en Android Studio utilizando Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy intentando embeber una página externa en Kotlin que posee ciertas particularidades y no la puedo embeberla. El link del sitio es: https://imagemeasurement.online/image/select
El código que estoy utilizando es:

1. ActivityMain

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val BASE_URL = "https://imagemeasurement.online/image/select"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // WebView
        binding.webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {
        }
        binding.webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
        }
        val settings = binding.webView.settings
        settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        binding.webView.loadUrl(BASE_URL)
    }
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me aparece ese error al intentar tomar o búscar una foto haciendo uso de la página

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios puntos que necesitas modificar para lograr cargar tu página web.

- No necesitas definir un `WebChromeClient` o `WebViewClient`
- Necesitas habilitar la [API de almacenamiento Web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) mediante `webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true` , ya que de forma predeterminada esta propiedad esta apagada.

  ```
   val url = "https://imagemeasurement.online/image/select"
   val webView = binding.mapWebview
   /*webView.webChromeClient = object: WebChromeClient() {
     }
     binding.webView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
    }
    */
    webView.loadUrl(url)
    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    webView.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
    webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true //*** very important!
  ```
- No debes usar "wrap_content", debes usar una medida fija o "match_parent" ya que esto puede ser causa que la página no pueda desplegarse correctamente.

  ```
   <WebView
    android:id="@+id/mapWebview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
  ```

Realiza las correcciones y podrás cargar sin problema tu página web dentro de tu WebView:

[image: Jorgesys WebView]

Comment: Muchas Gracias Jorge. Me funcionó tú solución para mostrar la página, aunque no permite tomar o cargar una foto

Comment: @FedericoMoreira eso que comentas es otro tema, este tipo de páginas para cargar recursos desde un android debe modificarse, ya que un WebView tiene limitaciones, por eso se opta subir el archivo de forma nativa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=webview+subir+archivo  Si deseas agregar otra pregunta ahora con este tema.

Comment: Hola @FedericoMoreira Recuerda que si las respuestas solucionan el problema planteado en la pregunta, hay que marcarlas como soluciòn, revisa [tour]